# I have a file and I want to diff it against all files in another directory to find which one is the same

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file foo, and a folder bar. The folder bar is a multilevel directory that eventually has files:

`bar/1/123/file
bar/2/12/file
bar/1/1/file`

foo is the same as one of the files and I am trying to find which one it is. How can I do this on linux? I imagine it will be with the find command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bash is not paleolithic, you can easily do that with pure bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in bar/**/*; do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]] && cmp -s foo "$f"; then
    printf "The matched file is '%s'\n" "$f"
    break
  fi
done
```

The `globstar` option, which allows the use of `bar/**/*` to mean "all files in the directory tree headed by `bar`, was introduced in bash 4.0, released in 2009. (Unfortunately, that version is not installed by default on OS X.)

The `break` in the loop is an optimization which stops the search after one file is found, since the problem description clearly stated "one of the files". If multiple matches are possible and you need to know all of them, remove the `break`.

Comment: this works, it didn't work on Mac, but I just moved all the data to my linux machine and it worked!

Comment: @jas, ...if you use MacPorts, Homebrew, etc., those can install a modern (4.x) bash for you. (Apple doesn't want to ship anything licensed GPLv3, hence their staying in the stone ages).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (avoiding compatibility concerns around different versions of bash) is to have `find` do the recursion for you and directly run `cmp` itself:

```
find bar -type f -exec cmp -s -- foo '{}' ';' -print
```

Answer (score -1):

Small one-liner that may help:

`for FILE in $(find . -type f -name file); do diff $FILE foo &>/dev/null && echo $FILE;done`

This will compare each file found in all subdirectories of the current location with the name "file" against the file named foo. If no diffs are found then the filename will be printed to screen. Note that you will not be spammed with the output of each diff.

Comment: If any filename has spaces, `for file in $(find ...)` will split it up into multiple words and treat each word as a different name. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), keeping in mind that the output of `find` is line-oriented when not using `-print0` (which is a much safer way to handle lists of files; see [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)).

Comment: Also, `diff` is much less efficient than `cmp -s`: whereas `cmp -s` can stop as soon as it sees a difference, or just if the files have different sizes, `diff` has to read them both and calculate the shortest edit difference between them.

Comment: @charles-duffy Thanks for the extra info and references. I had never really come across cmp before. Looks quite useful and I may adjust some of my scripts. You also make a good point about files with spaces.